# daterange picker both date same

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

Daterange picker with autoApply false

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    "autoApply": false,
    "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
    "minDate": "01/04/2017",
    "maxDate": "04/10/2017",
    "dateLimit" : {
    "days" : 60
    }

}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($('input[name="daterange"]').length) {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
      }
    });
});
```

Below [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/21wbxqht/) reference

When I select end date, both start date and end date textbox having same value,

How can I resolved this, I googled a lot, try some rnd but didn't get success

Comment: Doesn't seems to be reproducible in your jsfiddle

Comment: you select start date and end date, you will find both start date and end date textbox having same value

Comment: Seems that you are using old version

Comment: I don't find error in your jsfiddle.  The left date not mean start date , just when you select , the first one is start date, the second one which you select is end date。so when you select for third time is also start date even select  the right date；
In short, odd select is the start time, even select number is the end time；

Comment: Could you see the textbox value after selecting left date and right date, both textboxes gets same date

Comment: I don't find error in your jsfiddle too . Check my image http://prntscr.com/m02if4

Comment: @MinhNguyen, Plz try few times

Comment: The issue is when you do not move cursor after selecting end date

Answer (score 2):

You are using an older version of daterangepicker so update your daterangepicker js and css which can solve your issue.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    "autoApply": false,
    "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
    "minDate": "01/04/2017",
    "maxDate": "04/10/2017",
    "dateLimit": {
      "days": 60
    }

  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('input[name="daterange"]').length) {
      $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<br><br>
<p style="margin-left:10px;"><input type="text" name="daterange" value="" /></p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> force some scrolling
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `"autoApply": true` which will help to select the updated date on close the popover modal box

working example updated with this link : http://jsfiddle.net/498ogq1h/1/

Comment: I have to make "autoApply" false, I mentioned that in question

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam there is two way to do first you need to apply autoApply:true or you need to click on apply button to close the popup and update the selected value to the text box in you example small screen size apply button is not showing .. but on large screen its shown..

Comment: That I know, but before applying I need both text box should represent selected dates respectively